# Off-screen muted auto-play video is not working on Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, video

According to [Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/07/autoplay) you can auto-play HTML5 video on mobile as long as the `muted` attribute is set to enabled.

I am using [the following code](https://async-await.net/pages/off-screen-muted-auto-play-video.html) to test it.

```
<script>
  const video = document.createElement('video');
  // TODO: Include video in DOM to test the change.
  video.addEventListener('playing', event => alert('The video is playing off-screen.'));
  video.autoplay = 'true';
  video.muted = 'true';
  video.src = 'http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4';
</script>
```

Notice that I am not including the `video` element in DOM (I do post-processing on it using `canvas` so it needs not be shown). I get *IntersectionObserver.observe(target): target element is not a descendant of root* [which is caused by `muted` being set on the `video` but it not being in DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40825828/2715716).

On desktop Chrome 55.0.2883.87 m (64-bit) the `alert` is shown. On mobile Chrome 55.0.2883.91 (`navigator.userAgent`) it is not. When `video` is in DOM, both versions work. There are no extra warnings in the mobile browser compared to the desktop one.

Is this a bug in mobile Chrome?

Comment: "Playback will start automatically for a video element *once it comes into view* if both autoplay and muted are set..."

Comment: Ha, that's embarrassing. Need to turn off my code laser vision next time before I ask a question. Please post the comment as an answer so I can accept it. BTW I figured out that `display: none` doesn't count as being in the view but `visibility: hidden` does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/07/autoplay) (emphasis mine): "Playback will start automatically for a video element *once it comes into view* if both autoplay and muted are set..."

(BTW nice find per your comment that `display: none` doesn't count as being in the view but `visibility: hidden` does